Twilio Outbound Calling Issue
I am trying to make a call from a Twilio-registered number to a real phone number. The call connects successfully, but no voice is transferred. I want to achieve a realtime two way communication
Here is my code given below:
string accountSid = _configuration["TwillioCredentials:TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"];
string authToken = _configuration["TwillioCredentials:TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"];
string Fromno = _configuration["TwillioCredentials:TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER"];

var twimlResponse = new VoiceResponse();
var dial = new Dial();
dial.Number(toPhoneNumber);
twimlResponse.Append(dial);
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var call = CallResource.Create(
    from: new PhoneNumber(Fromno),
    to: new PhoneNumber(toPhoneNumber),
    twiml: new Twiml(twimlResponse.ToString()));


So you want to be able to talk into your computer microphone, and hear the other person through your speakers? Looks like there's a Voice SDK for that, but it supports JS, Android, iOS, and React Native

Okay, I will attempt to do it using JavaScript. Thank you for your assistance.
